# Stack Error after last line executed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

so I have this homework to do which I thought would be quite easy and quick to do but I keep getting this weird Stack error AFTER the last line of code is executed and the proper score is displayed on the console. The assignment is to use two functions to create a mini battleship game where I generate a 4x4 array a randomly place 6 ones inside it with the rest being zeros. Afterwards the user`enter code here` is asked x,y combinations until he's found all 6 ones with a maximum of 10 attempts. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;
#include <fstream>;

using namespace std;

const int DIMENSION = 4;



void creerGrille(int(&grilleNavale)[DIMENSION][DIMENSION]){


    //On remplit le tableau avec des zeros
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++){

            grilleNavale[i][j] = 0;

        }
    }


    //On place 6 "1"
    int i, j;//i et j seront les positions generes aleatoirement
    int k = 0;//k est une variable d iterations

    while(k <= 6) {//On ne connait pas le nombres d executions

        //On genere une position aleatoire
        i = rand()%7;
        j = rand()%7;

        ///On verifie que la case ne comporte pas deja un "1"
        ///Sinon on pourrait en placer moins que 6 en placant deux fois le meme 
        if (grilleNavale[i][j] != 1){

            grilleNavale[i][j] = 1;
            k++;

        }

    }//Fin while(k <= 6)


}//Fin creerGrille


/**
*  Genere un tableau 4x4 ou toutes les cellules contiennent un "0"
*  expecte six qui contiennent un "1". Les positions des cellules
*  qui contiennent des "1" sont determinees aleatoirement
*  \param
*  \param [out] grilleNavale: tableau de int de dimension 4x4
*  \return
*/
bool estValide(int x, int y, int(&grilleNavale)[DIMENSION][DIMENSION], int& score){

    if (grilleNavale[x][y] == 1){

        score++;
        grilleNavale[x][y] = 0;

        return true;//Puisque le coup etait valide

    }

    else{
        return false;
    }

}//Fin estValide


int main(){


    int nCoups = 0;
    int score = 0;
    int grilleNavale[DIMENSION][DIMENSION];
    creerGrille(grilleNavale);

    cout << "BATAILLE NAVALE ARGGGH\nVous allez entrez des coordonnes"
            "en (x,y) avec x et y comprit en 0 et 3";

    int x, y;
    bool estAcceptable;


    while ((score<6) && (nCoups<10)){


        cout << "\n\n\nEntrez les coodonnes de vote prochain coup"
            " x et y doivent etres en 0  et 3";

        //On valide les coordonnees entrees au clavier
        do{

            cout << "\n\nx = ";
            cin >> x;


            estAcceptable = ((x >= 0) && ( x <= 3));

            if (!estAcceptable){
                cout << "\nErreur position invalide\n";
            }

        } while (!estAcceptable);

        do{

            cout << "y = ";
            cin >> y;


            estAcceptable = ((y >= 0) && (y <= 3));

            if (!estAcceptable){
                cout << "Erreur position invalide\n";
            }

        } while (!estAcceptable);

        bool touche = estValide(x, y, grilleNavale, score);

        if (touche){
            cout << "\nARRRGHHH, touche";
        }
        else{
            cout << "\nFloushhh";
        }

        nCoups++;

    }//Fin while



    int scoreFinal = score;

    if (scoreFinal == 6){
        cout << "\n\nBravo, vous avez gagne !";
    }

    else{

        cout << "\n\nPouenpouenpouen, vous avez perdu, votre score: "
             << scoreFinal<<endl;   
    }


}//Fin main
```

(sorry left the documentation in french but I figured its a very simple program.

Comment: You've got a buffer-overflow. Your Initial `for` loop goes `<= 4`, it should be `< DIMENSION`.

Comment: I recommend replacing your C-Arrays with `std::array` (formerly from Boost) or `vector`.

Comment: This is also suspicious: `rand()%7` I guess 7 should also be `DIMENSION`.

Comment: The reason it happens after your last line of code is because you declare the `grilleNavale` array in main().  Since it is defined in main it is on the stack and when you write past the end of the array, you can write over the address on the stack of where `main()` should return to.

Answer (score 3):

The input array to `creerGrille` has 4 rows and columns, but you're looping through [0, 4], meaning accessing out of bounds elements.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){     // should be < 4
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++){ // should be < 4
```

Since you're using C++, I recommend changing the function to

```
void creerGrille( std::array<int, std::array<int, DIMENSION>, DIMENSION>& grilleNavale);
```

Yes, that's quite verbose, but you can use a `typedef` to cut down on the keystrokes. You'll also need to make corresponding changes in the calling code. The loop initializing the array elements can also be replaced by `std::fill_n`.

But we're not done yet! Even more problems lie ahead

```
i = rand()%7;
j = rand()%7;
```

This will result in `i` and `j` having values in the range [0, 6], and you're using these to index into the earlier mentioned array. Again, that's out of bounds element access, and hence undefined behavior.

Also, you shouldn't be using `rand()` at all in modern C++ code. Take a look at the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header and the far superior facilities it provides for random number generation.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch these out of bound elements. I guess what really threw me off is that the program actually ran the way it was supposed to and only reported the bug at the very end. Thank you Jason Goemaat for that explanation I really couldn't my wrap my mind around that one.